# Select multiple checkbox options with comma separated in a dropdown

Tags: jquery, angularjs

[find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LMRA.png)

Select multiple options in a dropdown onselecting a checkbox inside a dropdown and display with comma separated on dropdown

[onselecting a checkbox and display with comma separated on dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSYaj.png)

Comment: And what have you tried? What's your problem?

Comment: @sksmart you can use bootsrap-multiselect

Comment: @sksmart did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bootstrap-multiselect` with jquery to achieve your goal. It works in snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#yourselect').multiselect({
      includeSelectAllOption: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

<form id="form1">
  <div>
    <select id="yourselect" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
      <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
      <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```